# making a box container using foundation

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I have a psd that I am changing to css/html/js

The box measures 646 * 250 and has a white background/with a light gray border. Its also centered in the middle of a page.

I have foundation installed. My knowledge of foundation don't go beyond
navigation bars, grid systems, buttons, and forms. My css skills include looking up the tags on mozilla developer guide.

Is this something that I do with the css included from foundation or should I mix in sass with foundation?

What are some css tags that I should use? or think of?

I code and its working on the view of a rails application. The box is supposed to display data from the backend in a nicer format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Foundation is setup to ease responsive design into your application. This doesn't mix well with items that have to be a specific size.

Without knowing exactly what you are building and how it should behave when the screen real-estate gets smaller than the specified size, you can accomplish what you described with the following:

```
<div class="element">

</div>

.element {
    backround-color:#FFF;
    border:1px solid #CCC;
    height:250px;
    width:646px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Comment: I set the body tag in foundation to blue, because the layout outside the box is blue. The page is a white box with a blue background. Now the blue is covering the white, how do I force the white to appear?

Comment: The DOM nesting order and CSS rules determined how something is stacked. It's hard to tell without seeing an example.